# Problem while uploading the CSV file in Solr admin

Tags: csv, search, solr

I have a application which has a search facility and i am using Solr for searching. I am trying to upload the data as CSV file. But the data is not uploading to the Solr core properly.

Here is the curl command i am using

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/test_import/update/csv?commit=true&separator=%09&escape=%5c&encapsulator=%22' --data-binary @/tmp/college_data_20180809164959.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

this gives me an error

`java.io.IOException: (line 0) invalid char between encapsulated token end delimiter\n\tat org.apache.solr.internal.csv.CSVParser.encapsulatedTokenLexer`

If remove **encapsulator=%22** it uploads but not in good format.

This his how it got uploaded:

```
{
        "id":"8adb5378-aa58-427d-8ff4-fca4f31c96e6",
        "ID_College_Name_State_City_Address":["43387,,,,"],
        "_version_":1608318488833687552,
        "ID_College_Name_State_City_Address_str":["43387,,,,"]},
      {
        "id":"e29a0435-95c5-4d3c-bddf-eacef22f6859",
        "ID_College_Name_State_City_Address":["43388,apsce,,,"],
        "_version_":1608318488835784704,
        "ID_College_Name_State_City_Address_str":["43388,apsce,,,"]}
```

This is my csv file structure

```
"ID","College_Name","State","City","Address"
"43387","","","",""
"43388","apsce","","",""
```

Please help me in resolving this issue. Please let me know if you need any further information about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV file should be parsed perfectly fined with the default values for CSV parsing. Drop all the parameters you're giving.

The error message is because you've given the `separator` parameter as `%09`, which is the TAB character. Your values are not separated by a TAB character, but by the standard `,`.

```
separator=%09 # separated by TAB (wrong)
escape=%5c # escaped by \ (default)
encapsulator=%22 # encapsulated by " (default)
```

Since the parser is looking for values separated by `<TAB>`, having multiple `"` between separators indicates a parse error (which happens since `,` isn't given as a separator).

Comment: Thank you.. I did not check that, it worked.. But the field names are coming like underscores before and after the actual field names.. Like _ID_, _College_Name_

Comment: I removed double quotes from csv. Working properly now.

Comment: But that isn't the actual solution - the correct solution is to parse the file as the format it is.

Comment: How would i do that in this case?

Comment: That what my answer describes. You can just use the default values as they should work fine (instead of setting TAB as the separator), or explicitly set `,` as the separator as well.